# Why is each of these spectacle lenses creating two distinct refraction patterns?

Tags: optics, lenses, vision

Each of the spectacle lenses in this image cause two separate refraction patterns:

[image]

The patterns are different between the lenses because each eye is different, obviously, but why are there two different patterns *within* each lens?

Comment: Any chance it at least partly depends on the angle they make with the light source?

Comment: Are they varifocals or bifocals ?